# Implementing an algorithm to reset a maxjump for a ball inside a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, canvas

I'm creating a game where there is some block and a ball the user should make the ball jump into the blocks and reach a destination marked in green as you can see in my jsfidle:http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Fqk/4/ .
my problem is the jumping algorithm that i am using is set to make the ball reach a maxHeight set to `300` and it's working fine when delivering the ball to the first block but the problem occur when trying to jump to the next block wish i believe is because the max height is reached.So i am trying to figure out how i can reset the maxheight variable when the ball is on a block

```
 if (InAir) {
                for (var j = 0; j < Blocks.collection.length; j++) {
                    if (Collision(ball, Blocks.collection[j])) {
                        //console.log("collision");
                        ball.y = (Blocks.collection[j].blockY - ball.radius);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Sora, you still have several issues in your gameloop. It's not good idea to have only 1 state for a complex object like a ball. Especialy because your InAir state combines numeric and boolean values. Think about what other states are posible an handle them. If a ball is InAir he might be falling or jumping. He might be lying on the floor or on a Plattform. Implement these states and you will note by yourself, that you might readjust MaxHeight after the current height of the ball has changed.

Comment: BTW. I followed your question history while developing your game. You always take the first answer, paste it in your fiddle and ask the next question without thanking the ones that helped you. This has no style and this way you will never learn how to write a game. Did you so far write any line of the game on your own?

Comment: I am trying hard to understand the mentality and the way to how to start programing games .I'm still new in it and you should give me some credit and yes i did write lines of code on my own thank you :) ... and thank u for your time and hard work i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you store the ball's Y position and then calculate maxHeight each time from the ball's current Y position.

`maxHeight = ball.posY + 300`

Comment: Oh, i see. You don't past it into your fiddle by yourself.

Comment: I didn't update your fiddle beqause I was trying to point you in the right direction. I think it is more helpfull to give a more generic answer that can help you solve you specific problem and perhaps other's as well. If you did find my answer helpfull, please consider up-voting my answer. Cheers!